# Petty issues with tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

First of, I must clear out that tables are not my thing. I try to work as little as possible with tables because I am just an absolute wreckage when it comes to them.
However on this case, I'm trying to make a google plus-ish "news feed" of a chronology of scientific discoveries (for an assignment) and had to work with my darkest nightmare.

Everything went well, until I tried to change the space between each cell. It just won't let me make the space bigger, instead it'll augment either the padding or whatever, I even tried placing a transparent border, but only to fail.

Here's a jsfiddle: [jsfiddle.net/4J7sb/](http://jsfiddle.net/4J7sb/)

```
table.chronos {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 300;
 font-size: 1.3em;
 color: #121212;
 text-align: left;
}
```

Please full screen, thanks.

I want it to look more like http://plus.google.com, spacy and clean, but it won't let me.
I hate tables, so much.

Comment: You have good reason to hate tables, I would suggest changing to use divs instead,  you have way more control over positioning and spacing.  If you are stuck on tables then i think the property you are looking for is cell-spacing but this will effect the whole table ( dont think it works at the row level).

Comment: Yes, I'm a newbie designer (well, I've never had classes, I'm 15 and I just constantly analysed other codes and learned from them) so I thought I would sound bad by saying I hate tables, but it seems many others do too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Though it would be better to switch away from tables, you can do it using a CSS style like:

```
table.chronos {
    border-spacing: 20px;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```